# Graph $y = 3x + 1$ and $y = -x + 5$ by finding a table of values for each linear relation and identify the point of intersection

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Graph $y = 3x + 1$ and $y = -x + 5$ by finding a table of values for each linear relation.  Include your table of values and graph and identify the point of intersection.

Any hints/advice?

Comment: Pick two values of $x$ and figure out what $y$ is. Two points for each line will be enough to determine the line. From there you can probably eye-ball the intersection. Plug your guess back into the equations to make sure it works,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can find where they intersect by setting them equal to each other and solving. That is $$-x + 5 = 3x + 1 \Rightarrow \\ 5-1 = 3x + x \Rightarrow \\ 4 = 4x \Rightarrow \\ x = 1.$$ Then to find out the $y$ value we can plug it into either equation (because they meet at this point). $y = -x + 5 \Rightarrow y = -1 + 5 = 4.$ Thus they meet at $(1,4).$ Next, to create a table of values for each of them, we simply plug some value of $x$ into each equation (say, $x=-1,0,1$ for simplicity). We will then compute the values for $y$ for each equation at these $x$ values and turn this into a simple table. Then we plot the points and play connect the dots - making sure to label $(1,4)$ as instructed.